# Spring Boot app testing with database vendor specific JPA annotation

Tags: oracle, jpa, spring-boot

I got an app with an existing database that has Oracle only field type (e.g. "binary-float") mapped on the entity class with `@ColumnDefinitio`n annotation.

Things runs fine when running the app normally by launching the Application class.

However I can't seem to find a way to write junit tests easily. In another Spring Boot app, I have been using different profile to define a normal datasource that points to Oracle and a junit test datasource that points to the h2 in-memory db. I stayed mostly within JPAQL and common sql standard when using direct sql. Problem is, this scheme doesn't work if the JPA mapping annotation is database specific.

Any suggestions?

Comment: This isn't really spring boot specific as it wouldn't work in other cases too. As soon as you use vendor specific things in a `@ColumnDefinition` you are basically bound to that vendor. Work around remove the vendor specific info from `@ColumnDefinition` and modify the schema afterwards yourself.